# scale microservice architecture with multiple pods

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

I have 10 unique id and using that Id I fetch data from the database and I do a rest call with those data and I get an async response as pending as it takes some time to sync with the third party service, as soon as I receive the response from the API I update my data's(retrieved from DB) to pending?

**our solution:**

*

> the Initial idea was to have different Kubernetes pods for each unique
> ID by this each can scale independently the problem is that there
> could be pods that can be ideal and would be a waste of resources, we
> are trying to address this case

- 

Code flow:

1. we read the data in batch from mysqlDB with each ID
2. after reading it we then update those columns with status as pending so that on the next polling it doesn’t read the same data.
3. we then push the data to downstream and update the status as finished

is there any design pattern that I should look for or any suggestions that would be a help

Comment: what are your initial ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HieuLe , the Initial idea was to have different Kubernetes pods for each unique ID by this each can scale independently the problem is that there could be pods which can be ideal and would be waste of resources, we are trying to address this case 

our problem:
1. we read the data in batch from mysqlDB with each ID 
2. after reading it we then update those columns with status as read so that on the next polling it doesn’t read the same data and status as pending
3. we then push the data to downstream and update the status as finished

Comment: Thank you @hector for the clarification. What you described is a simplified version of any queue library. I recommend you find a library that implements queues using the database backend in your programming language. Then, the workflow becomes: (i) one process scan the db to find records that will be processed; (ii) that process just publishes the list of ids to the queue; (iii) you have some process (or pod) that subscribe to the queue. Each process does the task and updates the appropriate records. The library will take most dirty jobs and you will be free to focus on your business problem.